# Passing variable to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am passing data base objects to an array.

I need to include another variable to the array. The variable is $latitud_usuario.

Here is the code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $arr[] = array('nombre_doctor' => $obj->nombre_doctor,'apellido1_doctor' => $obj->apellido1_doctor,'apellido2_doctor' => $obj->apellido2_doctor,'ciudad_doctor' => $obj->ciudad_doctor, 'latitud_doctor' => $latitud_usuario);
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

If I create the array including only fetched objects, the JSON sent is ok, but after including the last array object:

```
'latitud_doctor' => $latitud_usuario
```

the JSON is not received as it should.

I guess this last array object expression is wrong.

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: can you show the `json_encode($arr);` output?and is there any errors?

Comment: please `print_r` array before encoding, at least the last portion, from where `$latitud_usuario` come from and what is the content in it?

Comment: i guess it is $obj -> latitud_usuario (instead of $latitud_usuario)

Comment: @FastSnail, it is ok, the problem lies at the value of $latitud_usuario, not at the array...thanks

Comment: @mvasco enable errors.so if there is a problem you can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $arr[] = array('nombre_doctor' => $obj->nombre_doctor,'apellido1_doctor' => $obj->apellido1_doctor,'apellido2_doctor' => $obj->apellido2_doctor,'ciudad_doctor' => $obj->ciudad_doctor, 'latitud_doctor' => $latitud_usuario);
           $arr['latitud_doctor']=$latitud_usuario;
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: don't think this is good answer.  in your array you have `'latitud_doctor' => $latitud_usuario` and outer the array add the `$arr['latitud_doctor']=$latitud_usuario;`.

Comment: can you tell why `'latitud_doctor' => $latitud_usuario` doesn't work ? it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that works (using a dummy $obj object):

```
$obj = (object) array('nombre_doctor'=> 6, 'apellido1_doctor' => 'whatever1', 'apellido2_doctor'  => 'whatever2', 
'ciudad_doctor' => 'Montreal', 'latitud_usuario' => '35463');
$arr[] = array('nombre_doctor' => $obj->nombre_doctor,'apellido1_doctor' => $obj->apellido1_doctor,
'apellido2_doctor' => $obj->apellido2_doctor,'ciudad_doctor' => $obj->ciudad_doctor, 
'latitud_doctor' => $obj->latitud_usuario);

echo json_encode($arr);
```